# Как я могу определить, каких символов в ArrayList больше всего?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, arraylist

Например, пользователь вводит число 300233. Мне нужно, чтобы выводилось что-то вроде "В числе больше всего - троек". Пока что я смог разделить число на символы,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList listOfNumbers = new ArrayList();
    int number = 0;
    System.out.println("Привет, введи число: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        number = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    while (number != 0) {
        listOfNumbers.add(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
}
```

но что делать дальше, понятия не имею

Comment: про esle if или switch что-нибудь знаешь?

Comment: Да, но ведь использовать switch с массивами нельзя. А если использовать else if, то решение сильно затянется. Или я не прав? Так что я не отказался бы от какого-нибудь хитроумного цыкла.

Comment: Ну цифр всего десять. Так почему бы не завести массив на 10 элементов со счётчиками цифр?

Answer (score 2):

Список для хранения отдельных цифр здесь лишний, имеет смысл завести массив на 10 элементов для подсчёта частоты цифр:

```java
int x = number;
int[] freq = new int[10];
int maxFreq = 0;
int maxDigit = -1;
while (number != 0) {
    int n = number % 10;
    if (++freq[n] > maxFreq) {
        maxDigit = n;
        maxFreq = freq[n];
    }
    number /= 10;
}
System.out.printf("Самая частая цифра в числе %d: %d, встречается %d раз(а)%n", 
    x, maxDigit, maxFreq
);
```

Однако в таком случае будет определяться *первая* самая частая цифра.
Для поиска всех цифр с наибольшей частотой надо проитерировать массив частот и выводить соответствующие цифры.

Answer (score 0):

#### Код

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Привет, введи число: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        
        int max = 0;
        int maxNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // идем от 0 до 9
            int count = num.length() - num.replaceAll(i + "", "").length(); // Сколько символов "i"
            if(count > max) {
                max = count;
                maxNum = i;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Ответ: " + maxNum);
    }
}
```

#### Console:

```
Привет, введи число: 
> 300233
Ответ: 3
```